# When is user data seen by server

Tags: security, internet, client-server

Can someone from server side know the data entered in a form by user, even when "Submit" or "Next" button has not been pressed? 
I had entered the data, but opened another tab in the browser and spent a half-hour or so there. On returning I deleted the entered data, aborted the process and had never pressed "Next" button. 
Yet someone called from their side and asked why I hadn't completed the process. They had all those data like phone number. How is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form could have client-side JavaScript events attached to it, and the JS code could submit updates to the server every time you changed a field. (The technique used to be known as [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).)

For example, many webmail and forum sites – including this website – do the same thing in order to save "drafts" while you're still typing. There's no button to save a draft in Gmail, it's done au­to­mat­i­cal­ly through a JavaScript "on key release" event.

In most browsers you can see this happening if you open the "Developer tools" window (<kbd>F12</kbd>) and go to its "Network" tab, which will then show all JavaScript-based network requests as 'xhr'.

Of course, the automatically-submitted draft data should *normally* not be considered by the system as a full submission – but I guess sometimes the marketing team's requirements bypass common sense.

(Several years ago, it was found out that Facebook used this method to analyze all status updates that people typed in and erased without posting. It didn't lead to unwanted phone calls, though.)

Answer (score 1):

The moment you load a page into a browser window, it can see mouse movements over this window and key presses while the window is active.

This is usefull (e.g. for browser games) but can also have unintended consequences - nothing stops a simple form to be programmed in a way, that it submits the data while it is being entered, not only when a submit button is clicked.

Comment: It's very important to make the destinction between the client-side (in-browser) and server-side. All of what you describe is true for the client-side application, but it could easily be misinterpreted to mean "_the page, including server-side_" by someone who isn't as technically cognizant of this distinction. It's also important to state that the client *could* share this data with the server, but that behaviour wouldn't typically be expected.

Comment: @Attie: This distinctiion is only theoretical: Since the client can pass whatever information it has to the server (e.g. via AJAX or websockets), in practice the server actually has access to the same information.

Comment: I fully agree that its _feasable_ for the server to have access to the same information as the client, but I disagree about the presentation, implicit expectation that it would and subtle conflation of "_page_" vs "_backend and frontend_". On re-reading, your final statement is probably sufficient ("_nothing stops a simple form ..._")